# lista enlazada manual ingresada por teclado

Tags: java, lista

al crear la lista manualmente por teclado tengo el siguiente inconveniente, la variable nodo solo almacena el valor actual. ListaEnlazada1 nodo = new ListaEnlazada1();

```
package lista.enlazada1;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ListaEnlazada1 {

public String marca;
public String modelo;
public int kilometraje;
public ListaEnlazada1 nodosiguiente;


public static void main(String[] args) {
/* enter the number of nodes to be created */
Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Digite la cantidad de nodos a ingresar)");
int n,contador=0;
n=leer.nextInt();

/* the three data of the node is entered */
for (int i =1; i <= n; i++){
   ListaEnlazada1 nodo = new ListaEnlazada1();
    System.out.print("ingrese la marca ");
      nodo.marca=leer.next();
      System.out.print("ingrese el modelo ");
      nodo.modelo=leer.next();
      System.out.print("ingrese el kilometraje ");
      nodo.kilometraje=leer.nextInt();

/* the node is created  */  

 if(contador==0){
 nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
 contador ++;
 } else {
 nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;
 contador ++;
 }    

/* nodes are printed  */
for ( i =1; i <= n; i++){
System.out.println("marca " +nodo.marca+ "\n");
    System.out.println("modelo " +nodo.modelo+ "\n");
    System.out.println("kilometraje " +nodo.kilometraje+ "\n");
    System.out.println("apuntador " +nodo.nodosiguiente + "\n");    

}

}

}

}
```

debo cambiar el codigo para que la variable cambie el nombre cada vez que entre al for, por ejemplo la primera iteracion nodo1, la segunda iteracion nodo2, etc. lo que he probado nada ha funcionado.

Comment: Que es lo que quieres lograr?

Answer (score 0):

._ Hola Ives.

Tu codigo esta lleno de errores, desde los mas basicos de logica hasta los mas graves como falta de teoria y conocimientos de Programacion orientada a objetos y como se enlanzan los nodos de una lista.

**Errores de logica:**

Tenes un FOR dentro de otro FOR. (segun tu logica, si yo pido a tu sistema 10 nodos, por cada uno vas a tratar de mostrarme la lista entera)
El segundo for (que muestra la lista, deberia ir afuera del primero). O sea primero lleno mi lista, despues muestro.

Analiza mejor este IF

```
        if (contador == 0) {
            nodo.nodosiguiente = null;
            contador++;
        } else {
            nodo.nodosiguiente = nodo;
            contador++;
        }
```

Seria lo mismo que decir: si mi 'contador' vale 0, a la variable 'numero' le asigno cero, y a la variable 'numero' le asigno la variable 'numero'. No tiene sentido lo que estas haciendo ahi.

**Errores de POO:**

Para crear una lista enlazada necesitas:

**Definir una clase *NODO* (ejemplo)**

```
public class Nodo<T> {

private T dato;
private Nodo<T> siguiente;

/**
 * Constructor por defecto
 */
public Nodo(){
    siguiente=null;
 }

/**
 * Le pasamos un dato al nodo
 * @param p 
 */
public Nodo(T p){
    siguiente=null;
    dato = p;
}

/**
 * Le pasamos un dato y su siguiente nodo al nodo
 * @param t Dato a insertar
 * @param siguiente Su sisguiente nodo
 */
public Nodo(T t, Nodo<T> siguiente){
    this.siguiente=siguiente;
    dato = t;
}

public T getDato() {
    return dato;
}

public void setDato(T dato) {
    this.dato = dato;
}

public Nodo<T> getSiguiente() {
    return siguiente;
}

public void setSiguiente(Nodo<T> siguiente) {
    this.siguiente = siguiente;
}
```

}

**Definir la clase Lista, con el atributo NODO adentro, y metodos como
insertar(),verVacia(), etc...**

```
public class ListaEnlazada<T>{

//Atributos
private Nodo<T> primero;

/**
 * Constructor por defecto
 */
public ListaEnlazada(){
    listaVacia();
}

/**
 * Vacia la lista
 */
private void listaVacia(){
    primero = null;
}

/**
 * Indica si la lista esta vacia o no
 * @return True = esta vacia
 */
public boolean estaVacia(){
    return primero == null;
}

/**
 * Inserta un objeto al principio de la lista
 * @param t Dato insertado
 */
public void insertarPrimero(T t){
    Nodo<T> nuevo = new Nodo<>(t);

    if (!estaVacia()){
        //Sino esta vacia, el primero actual pasa a ser
        // el siguiente de nuestro nuevo nodo
        nuevo.setSiguiente(primero);
    }

    //el primero apunta al nodo nuevo
    primero=nuevo;

}

/**
 * Inserta al final de la lista un objeto
 * @param t Dato insertado
 */
public void insertarUltimo(T t){

    Nodo<T> aux = new Nodo<>(t);
    Nodo<T> rec_aux;

    if (estaVacia()) {
        insertarPrimero(t);
    }else {
        rec_aux = primero;

        //Buscamos el ultimo nodo
        while(rec_aux.getSiguiente() != null){
            rec_aux=rec_aux.getSiguiente();
        } 

        //Actualizamos el siguiente del ultimo
        rec_aux.setSiguiente(aux);
    }
}

/**
 * Quita el primer elemento de la lista
 */
public void quitarPrimero(){
    Nodo<T> aux;
    if (!estaVacia()){
        aux=primero;
        primero = primero.getSiguiente();
        aux=null; //Lo marcamos para el recolector de basura
    }
}

/**
 * Quita el ultimo elemento de la lista
 */
public void quitarUltimo(){
    Nodo<T> aux=primero;
    if(aux.getSiguiente()==null)
       //Aqi entra, si la lista tiene un elemento
       listaVacia();
    if(!estaVacia()) {
        aux=primero;

        //Buscamos el penultimo, por eso hay dos getSiguiente()
        while(aux.getSiguiente().getSiguiente() != null){
            aux=aux.getSiguiente();
        }

        //Marcamos el siguiente del antepenultimo como nulo, eliminando el ultimo
        aux.setSiguiente(null);
    }

}        

/**
 * Devuelve el último elemento de la lista
 * @return Último elemento
 */
public T devolverUltimo(){
    T elemen = null;
    Nodo<T> aux;
    if (!estaVacia()){
        aux = primero;

        //Recorremos
        while(aux.getSiguiente() != null){
            aux = aux.getSiguiente();
        }
        elemen = aux.getDato();
    }
    return elemen;
}
```

**Y por ultimo necesitas una clase MAIN, donde podras instanciar tu clase LISTA y pedir al usuario que elija la cantidad de nodos/datos que quiere ingresar.**